# VPN login on home router

Tags: windows-xp, router, vpn

I connect to the Internet via a Linksys Wireless N router. I then VPN into my corporate network using the windows XP VPN client. The connection works fine, except after I disconnect, I need to reboot the router in order to reconnect again (it will just hang on the verifying username/password dialog).

Does anyone know why this might happen?

Comment: Have you tried installing the latest firmware for your model?

Comment: I'll be sure to try that right now.